# How to count number of posts in database without mysql_num_rows?

Tags: php, sql

How to count number of posts in database without mysql_num_rows?

I'm using this:

```
$post_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user='$user'");

$number = mysql_num_rows($post_query);
```

but mysql_num_rows always returns 1 even when there are 0 posts? I need something that will return 0 when there are 0 posts.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: You might want to read this answer first, just to make sure that you understand what you're asking for: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17992/8374

Comment: `but mysql_num_rows always returns 1 even when there are 0 posts? I need something that will return 0 when there are 0 posts.`  I have never encountered a problem like this.. If my database contains no rows, i get an output of `0` not a minimum of `1`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT count (*) FROM posts WHERE user='$user'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE user='$user'
```

Read up on your sql first 2 seconds searching on google would have given you the answer

Comment: I found SELECT count(*) on google, but I still don't know how to implement it. Should I do $post_query = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE user='$user'");, but that doesn't create anything.

Comment: not count() its count(*) or count(column_name)

Comment: we've posted the exact syntax for you already

Comment: It works now. I needed to add $number = mysql_result($number_query, 0); after $number_query = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE user='$user'");. That is what I was asking for. I already knew about SELECT count(*). You didn't needed to give me negative votes.